# TCLOO: How to distinguish a basic type from an object

Tags: tcl

How can I distinguish a basic type (like string) from an ::oo::object in TclOO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can determine precisely if a value is the handle for an object by using [`info object isa object`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M68):

```
if {[info object isa object $thing]} {
    puts "Hey, $thing is an object!"
}
```

Generally speaking though, Tcl's type system has all values being at least *nominally* strings. More strictly, every value is serializable to a string. Some values have other natures as well (e.g., numbers know about their numeric-ness as well). TclOO object handles are strings, and command names (and hence can be `rename`d), and (of course) object handles.

Answer (score 0):

Stupid answer:

```
# Since a normal string is unlikly to be "::oo::object", this will return 1
# if the argument is not ::oo::object
proc is_oo_object args {
    string equals $arg ::oo::object
}

# gettype - higly accurate
proc gettype arg {
    # EIAS
    return "string"
}
```

Simple answer: you can't. If someone passes you the name of an object, it's a string.
(See the Tcl/Tk wiki for [EIAS](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3018))

You can try to guess if it is a ::oo::object if you check if there exists a command with that name:

```
if {[llength [namespace which $arg]]} {
    ....
}
```

This still don't mean that this is an ::oo::object.
You could try to inspect it with `expr {[catch {info object class $arg ::oo::object} res] && $res}`, but who tells you that someone wanted to pass `oo::class` as string?